# Migrate SharedPreferences to new SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In our app, we've used `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` for our shared prefs.  We're now required to use a named prefs instance (for A/B testing).

So now we get the prefs using `context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

What I need to do is move all of the stored prefs from the old instance to the new one.  Is there a simple solution to do this?

I'm able to get the map of the old prefs but not sure how to write it to the new prefs since writing requires type ("putInt", "putString", etc).

Here's where I've hit a road block:

```
private void convertToPrivateSharedPrefsIfNeeded() {
    SharedPreferences oldPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Map<String, ?> oldPrefsMap = oldPrefs.getAll();

    SharedPreferences newPrefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : oldPrefsMap.entrySet()) {

    }

}
```

I'm guessing that I'm on the right track but not sure what to put in the for loop here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could involving checking the return type of `entry.getValue()` for each of supported types and call the related method on the editor object. E.g.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : oldPrefsMap.entrySet()) {
     Object current = entry.getValue();
     if (current instanceof Integer) {
           newPrefs.edit().putInt(...);
     } else if (current instanceof ....) {}
}
```

that should do for the primitive types supported by the `SharedPreference`.
Alternatively you can try rename the file. The path of the file is

```
 /data/data/your.app.package/shared_prefs/
```

and your app should be able access that directory directly

Comment: I actually didn't know you could rename the shared prefs file.  that's fantastic news!  I'm also made at myself for not checking the value's type... great suggestion there